# Names of some fractions

Tags: mathematics, fractions

Which are the names of fractions like 1/3, 2/3, 4/3, which are now in disuse or render obsolete. I saw a bit of time ago, a book that mentioned the names associated to those fractions (instead of the modern one-third, etc), but, I can not remember title of the book. It was a book regarding arithmetic and algebra. Some web related to those topics?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Those three fractions. I would not say in old english. In the period of 1800s

Comment: Ver probably, the words for the above fractions with latin/greek/ prefixes

Comment: @RamonioTaxus Please [edit] more information into your question; don't leave important stuff in comments. What you might also explain is what you mean by the "name": those fractions are [vulgar fractions](/q/342093). Are you saying that *thirds* have a **particular** name and asking what that is?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you are looking for the word *tierce*. It appears that an archaic meaning of this is *one third*. However, I don't believe that this meaning was ever common in English, and it is now completely forgotten.

From [Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tierce)

> (obsolete) A third.

From [*etymonline:*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tierce)

> Also used in Middle English for "a third part" (late 15c.), "the third hour of the canonical day" (ending at 9 a.m.), late 14c., and, in astronomy and geometry, "sixtieth part of a second of an arc."

Comment: Even more obscure is "farthing", which once meant a quarter. It's only real use was as an archaic unit of old British currency (abolished 1971) and used by J R R Tolkien for the four subdivisions of the Shire.

Comment: My only experience with "tierce" is from fencing, where it was a fancier name for the third hand position (which, indeed, we called "third").

Comment: It's also an [obsolete measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tierce_(unit)#:~:text=The%20tierce%20(also%20terse)%20is,defined%20as%2042%20US%20gallons.) of volume — a third of a pipe, or 42 gallons.